# Java graphic class proposition

Tags: java, architecture, oop, graphical-programming

I'm working a java+swing+miglayout project we settled on a class design for graphical classes that inherits from JPanel & JFrame, here is the skelletons :

```
class GammaFrame extends JFrame {
private JPanel __pane__ = null;

public static GammaFrame open(...) {

    _instance = GammaFrame()

    __pane__ = _instance.getContentPane();
    __pane__.setLayout(new MigLayout(...));

    _instance.__init__()

    # do logic job if any

    return _instance;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        GammaFrame.open();
    }
}

class GammaPanel extends JPanel {

public static GammaPanel create(...) {

    _instance = GammaPanel()

    _instance.setLayout(new MigLayout(...));

    _instance.__init__()

    # do logic job if any

    return _instance;
    }

    public static void main(String argv[]) {
        JPanel panel = GammaPanel.create()
        JFrame frame = new JFrame()
        frame.getContentPane().add(panel)

        # 
        # more settings here
        # 

        frame.setVisible(true)
    }
}
```

what may be the flaws of this design ?

Comment: Please, no underscores. This isn't PHP

Comment: @Lord.Quackstar :  it's impossible for me to switch from PHP, Java, Python, Javascript without custom/common pratices.

Answer (score 3):

The major drawback I see is the fact that your `GammaPanel` is not automatically used inside the `GammaFrame` class.

You shouldn't use a `main` method to generate the GUI. You should let the constructor of `GammaFrame` handle instantiating its components and showing them; otherwsie you will have to instantiate everything in the `main` method, but this is unsuitable if you have multiple frames and many components.

Usually you tend to encapsulate a whole frame, with its content, in just one class that may have inner classer for custom components (like your `GammaPanel`).

If you plan to have shared components, like a custom graph, you can declare it separately and then instantiate and use it in different frames.

It is critical that you build your GUI components on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17409_01/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html).

You may want to consider the benefits of model-view-controller design, as suggested in this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3072979).